Azure IoT Edge device not connecting to IoT Hub
I followed this tuturial to the tee: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/how-to-provision-single-device-linux-on-windows-symmetric?view=iotedge-1.4&tabs=azure-portal but I'm getting errors I don't know how to resolve
here are some:
running command  iotedge system logs -- -f

running command iotedge check --verbose

In Azure

Clicking on "Error" I get:

I have tried many things from modifying the connection config file (/etc/aziot/config.toml), to playing around with self-signed certificates, opening up ports 8883,443 and 5671 on the host machine and the linux vm, re-installing the runtime.
Also stuff from here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/troubleshoot?view=iotedge-1.4
Nothing works.

refer to Deploy your first IoT Edge module to a Windows device

The error device is offline displayed since the device is offline and not running. I followed this document to deploy the IoT Edge module and make it run.



Creating an edge device


Deploy a module:

Select Devices under Device Management and choose the target device ID.

I followed document to develop and debug Azure IoT Edge modules using Visual Studio.

Used this code for the simulated temperature sensor module designed for use in an Azure IoT Edge from git.

Select Set Modules and add a module from Azure Marketplace(Simulated Temperature Sensor).

Configure routes and review the deployment, then create it.




Copy the connection string or retrieve the connection string for your device using

az iot hub device-identity connection-string show --device-id myEdgeDevice --hub-name {hub_name}

Steps to install and start the IoT Edge runtime:
Run PowerShell as an administrator on your Windows device and enable Hyper-V using:
   Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V -All

Download the IoT Edge for Linux on Windows installer using:
  $msiPath = $([io.Path]::Combine($env:TEMP, 'AzureIoTEdge.msi'))
  Invoke-WebRequest "https://aka.ms/AzEFLOWMSI_1_4_LTS_X64" -OutFile $msiPath

Replace the URL with  "https://aka.ms/AzEFLOWMSI_1_4_LTS_ARM64" if you're using ARM64 architecture.

Install IoT Edge for Linux on Windows using:
Start-Process -Wait msiexec -ArgumentList "/i","$([io.Path]::Combine($env:TEMP, 'AzureIoTEdge.msi'))","/qn"




Set the execution policy to AllSigned using:
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy AllSigned -Force





Deploy IoT Edge runtime using:
Deploy-Eflow




Provision your device using the device connection string retrieved earlier:
Provision-EflowVm -provisioningType ManualConnectionString -devConnString "<CONNECTION_ST>"





Connecting to a virtual machine

Connect-EflowVm


Use the command to list the IoT Edge modules running on your device
sudo iotedge list

View the messages being sent from the temperature sensor module
sudo iotedge logs SimulatedTemperatureSensor -f

You can see the status of running in the IoT module


For more refer to this develop and debug modules for Azure IoT Edge


It's not working. I'm getting the exact same error messages

what are getting after running sudo iotedge list , sudo iotedge logs edgeAgent -f and sudo iotedge logs SimulatedTemperatureSensor -f

this my data sudo iotedge list  1   sudo iotedge logs edgeAgent -f 2 and sudo iotedge logs SimulatedTemperatureSensor -f  3 after  Provision-EflowVmand Connect-EflowVm. In azure.

sudo iotedge list give me no results. Because the connection is not working, it's not fetching the container from IoT Hub.

@SmokerJones It really weird problem with no results. Any way you found the solution with self-signed certificates, it got it working. good Know.

In the tuturial, it says to use symmetric key authentication. This did not work so a combination of this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/how-to-provision-single-device-linux-x509?view=iotedge-1.4&tabs=azure-portal%2Cubuntu which shows you how to setup a device using self-signed certificates and this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/how-to-create-test-certificates?view=iotedge-1.4&tabs=windows which shows you how to create self-signed certificates, I got it working.
